# Как правильно обращаться с return в моём случае

Tags: xcode, objective-c

Помогите, пожалуйста, с кодом. Как правильно написать что-то подобное?
У меня много кнопок, и все они одинаковые, различие только в рендоме. Чтоб не писать много одного и того же, решил в переменную генерировать `try_return`, но возращать её не получаеться.

> Void method ‘pushToSecond2:’ should
> not return a value.

Я то не против, но как сделать правильно?

```
  - (IBAction)pushToSecondMain:(id)sender
    {
        i_1=try_return;
        if (i_1==0) //выполняю разные операции
        {
            i_1=1;
        };
    }

    - (IBAction)pushToSecond2:(id)sender
    {
        [self pushToSecondMain:nil];
        try_return=arc4random()%20; //генирирую с рендомом 20
        return try_return;
    }

    - (IBAction)pushToSecond3:(id)sender
    {
        [self pushToSecondMain:nil];
        try_return=arc4random()%30; //генирирую с рендомом 20
        return try_return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IBAction` синоним void (нужен для Interface Builder'a). Да и возвращать из такого метода собственно нечего, так как вызывает его не ваш код а код `UIKit`. Вам просто-напросто нужно запоминать сгенерированное значение Вашего рандома в какой-то instance variable вашего класса (и похоже Вы это уже делаете: `try_return`). И использовать где нужно. Проше говоря из `IBAction`-методов уберите `return`'ы и все заиграет.

Comment: Спасибо, всё действительно заиграло

Answer (score 1):

Можете проставить у каждой кнопки свой тэг в сторибоарде: свойство `tag` от 1 до  n.
Все кнопки за мапить на один метод:

```
- (IBAction)pushToSecondMain:(id)sender
```

Если вы в дебагере посмотрите то в `sender` должна лежать кнопка, которую вы нажали, и следовательно ее номер `tag`'а.
Ну и в теле метода можно написать следующее:

```
- (IBAction)pushToSecondMain:(id)sender
{
    i_1=try_return;
    if (i_1==0) //выполняю разные операции
    {
        i_1=1;
    };
   try_return=arc4random()%(sender.tag * 10);
//поскольку в вернуть объект IBAction нельзя, return  работать не будет.
}
```

try_return глобальная переменка инстанса, там уж придумайте че с ней делать дальше.

Comment: Спасибо, отличный вариант!